# Scrape table from url

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from "https://www.investing.com/equities/pre-market" here the picture of what I need :[image]

```
class="datatable_table__D_jso PreMarketMostActiveStocksTable_preMarketMostActiveStocksTable__9yGOv datatable_table--mobile-basic__W2ilt datatable_table--freeze-column__7YoIE"
```

It seems that this HTML code contains the table, I tried to scrape using
`soup.find` but I get no result.

here is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.investing.com/equities/pre-market"
html = requests.get(url).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'datatable_row__qHMpQ'})
print(soup)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check your response you may run into a *Cloudflare* issue.

Comment: What is a Cloudflare  issue?

Comment: Cloudflare is a global network designed to make everything you connect to the Internet secure, private, fast, and reliable. In other words, you're not getting what you want because the site's protected by Cloudflare and they don't want you to scrape them.

Comment: I see thanks for the answer. BTW how did you know this specific website has Cloudflare ?

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment - First at all check the response from the server, cause that is the base for your scraping - In this case it will give you following information *Why have I been blocked? This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.*

Comment: you can also use a Chrome Extension called Wappalyzer to check which tecnologies these websites are using (like cloudflare)

Answer (score 2):

The class you're using belongs to the header **row** of the table, not the `table` tag itself. <sub>(It's indicated by the class name itself - "datatable_**row**__qHMpQ"...)</sub>
[image: table html]

You can use one of the table classes instead (like `datatable_table__D_jso`) or you could use the `data-test` attribute:

```py
table = soup.find('table', {'data-test': "pre-market-most-active-stocks-table"})
```

---

```py
# import pandas
print(pandas.read_html(table.prettify())[0].to_markdown(index=False))
```

prints

```
| Name                | Symbol   |   Last |   Chg. | Chg. %   | Vol.   | Time     |
|:--------------------|:---------|-------:|-------:|:---------|:-------|:---------|
| Jiuzi Holdings Inc  | JZXN     | 0.24   | 0.092  | +62.09%  | 19.14M | 09:27:41 |
| OpGen Inc           | OPGN     | 0.245  | 0.12   | +96.00%  | 16.41M | 09:27:41 |
| Powerbridge         | PBTS     | 0.1001 | 0.0084 | +9.16%   | 12.07M | 09:26:40 |
| Faraday Future Int. | FFIE     | 0.57   | 0.11   | +24.59%  | 12.03M | 09:27:56 |
| Magenta Therapeuti. | MGTA     | 1.45   | 0.3    | +26.09%  | 9.12M  | 09:27:58 |
| Starry Holdings     | STRY     | 0.122  | 0.022  | +21.50%  | 8.34M  | 09:26:57 |
| Netcapital Inc      | NCPL     | 3.03   | 1.64   | +117.99% | 6.51M  | 09:27:59 |
| China Pharma        | CPHI     | 0.1449 | 0.0044 | +3.13%   | 3.55M  | 09:26:52 |
| 111 Inc             | YI       | 3.81   | 0.27   | +7.63%   | 2.98M  | 09:28:00 |
| Amesite             | AMST     | 0.369  | 0.059  | +19.03%  | 2.45M  | 09:21:45 |
```

---

---

**EDIT:** full code with some additions for debugging and/or error handling:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os

url = "https://www.investing.com/equities/pre-market"
resp = requests.get(url)
# resp.raise_for_status() # halt program right here if bad response

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content)
table = soup.find('table', {'data-test':"pre-market-most-active-stocks-table"})

if table is None and resp.status_code == 200: # ok respose, but no table
    hfn = 'MISSING_DATA investing-com_equities_premarket.html'
    with open(hfn, 'wb') as f: f.write(resp.content) 
    print('no such table found - inspect [on editor]: ', os.path.abspath(hfn))
elif table: print(pd.read_html(table.prettify())[0].to_markdown(index=False))
else: print(f'{resp.status_code} {resp.reason} - failed to scrape {url}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting this error - "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'" although I have `from prettify import *`

Comment: @RaphaelHen this a different `prettify` that comes from bs4 Tags, and does not have to be imported `from prettify...`; it seems that there is some issue with the response you get from `requests.get`, like some suggested in the comments. I've added an edit to my answer - please try my full code and see if it clears up the situation (if it saves and html file, see how the html in the file is different from expected...)

Comment: Thanks for your time. now with the new code I am getting "403 Forbidden - failed to scrape https://www.investing.com/equities/pre-market"

Comment: @RaphaelHen (I don't get that error) but this means the site is blocking you....So you need to [set good headers](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-fake-and-rotate-user-agents-using-python-3/#therightwaytorotateuseragentsinanyprogram) [with `requests`] or try using [instead of `requests`] something like [cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) or [HTMLSession](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/)

Comment: I used cloudscraper and it works great. thanks you! also by using this will I be blocked again in the future or its permeant?

Comment: Also, 1 more question. how can I have access to the pandas data? I want to have the symbols as a list. thanks again.

Comment: @RaphaelHen I'm not sure - you can try in a few hours or tomorrow to check and see. Some sites have stricter security than others. [Btw, you can get blocked with cloudscraper/HTMLSession  too, but it's less likely.]

Comment: For *"the symbols as a list"*: either **`symList = list(pd.read_html(table.prettify())[0]['Symbol'])`** **OR** `iepDf = pd.read_html(table.prettify())[0]` [to have the dataframe as `iepDf` first] followed by `symList = list(iepDf['Symbol'])` should do